# Add zxing to XCode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, zxing

I am adding zxing to my project.

- I first copied the iphone folder to
  my project directory.
- Then copied the cpp folder to my
  project directory.
- Dragged the ZXingWidget.xcodeproj
  into XCode.
- Added the dependency.
- Linked the library.
- Now for header search paths, I don't
  know what to put. Here's what my
  setup looks like:
  [image]

For header search paths, I entered:

- “zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes"
- “zxing/cpp/core/src/”

But when I try to import QRCodeReader.h it's telling me it's not found. So I am guessing it has something to do with header search paths. Can someone firm that the paths I entered are correct? If not, what could be wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Following tutorial might help you: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that Recursive check box has been checked in Build Settings where ZXingWidget/Classes are added to the Header Search Paths.